# TypeScript: Enforce generic inferred type parameter in function

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there a way to restrict the `run` call below to be strict about the type allowed by the type parameters specified to the `RequestType<>`? The return type `R` seems to work, but `RQ` isn't strict.

```
class RequestType<RQ, R> {
    constructor(public readonly method: string) { }
 }

interface FooRequest {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

interface FooResponse {
    foobar: string;
}

const FooRequestType = new RequestType<FooRequest, FooResponse>("foo");

function run<RQ, R>(type: RequestType<RQ, R>, request: RQ): R {
    // real code here
    return {} as R;
}
```

Here are the calls

```
const foo1 = run(FooRequestType, {}); // want an error here
const foo2 = run(FooRequestType, {
    foo: "foo" // want an error here
});
const foo3 = run(FooRequestType, {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar",
    baz: "" // error here -- good
});
```

Here is a link to the [TypeScript playgound](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20RequestType%3CRQ%2C%20R%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20method%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FooRequest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FooResponse%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foobar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20FooRequestType%20%3D%20new%20RequestType%3CFooRequest%2C%20FooResponse%3E(%22foo%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20run%3CRQ%2C%20R%3E(type%3A%20RequestType%3CRQ%2C%20R%3E%2C%20request%3A%20RQ)%3A%20R%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20R%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo1%20%3D%20run(FooRequestType%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20want%20an%20error%20here%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%20%3D%20run(FooRequestType%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20%22foo%22%20%2F%2F%20want%20an%20error%20here%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20foo3%20%3D%20run(FooRequestType%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%22bar%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20%22%22%20%2F%2F%20error%20here%20--%20good%0D%0A%7D)%3B). Any help is appreciated -- Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html): *Because TypeScript is a structural type system, type parameters only affect the resulting type when consumed as part of the type of a member.*

In your case, `RequestType<{},FooResponse>` and `RequestType<FooRequest, FooResponse>` have the exact same structure, so in line

`run(FooRequestType, {});`

the types are correctly inferred as

`run<{},FooResponse>(FooRequestType: RequestType<{}, FooResponse>, {}: {})`

---

One way to deal with that is to add some (bogus if needed) property to `RequestType`, such that `RequestType<RQ1,R>` is different from `RequestType<RQ2,R>`. That property could be

```
class RequestType<RQ, R> {
    private readonly acc: (req: RQ) => RQ | undefined;
    constructor(public readonly method: string) { }
}
```

Note that for this particular solution to succeed you need to enable `strictFunctionTypes` option. Otherwise, `(req: FooRequest) => FooRequest` will be assignable to `(req: {}) => {}` and so `FooRequestType` will still be assignable to `RequestType<{}, FooResponse>`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html).

---

A different approach would be to not allow TypeScript to infer the wrong type for `request`, and instead make it infer the type for `requestType` (changed from `type` for readability):

```
type RequestOf<RT> = RT extends RequestType<infer RQ, any> ? RQ : never;
type ResponseOf<RT> = RT extends RequestType<any, infer R> ? R : never;
function run<RT extends RequestType<any, any>>(
    requestType: RT,
    request: RequestOf<RT>
): ResponseOf<RT> {
    return {} as ResponseOf<RT>;
}
```

Now, TypeScript will "guess" correctly that `RT` is `RequestType<FooRequest, FooResponse>`. Then,

```
type RequestOf<RT> = RT extends RequestType<infer RQ, any> ? RQ : never;
```

basically says: if `RT` is `RequestType<RQ, something>`, make `RequestOf<RT>` equal to that `RQ`. For more on that `infer` magic, see [Type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).